# Is it possible to archive after build in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is it possible to archive the last build without rebuilding. IE. Without selecting "Build and archive" from the menu?
I would like my last build to show up in Organizer as archived.
Thanks.

Comment: just a quick comment, it is `Xcode` not `XCode` ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Archive menu command to archive the last build *without rebuilding*. Archive is found in Product > Archive. Note that you can only archive builds targeting iOS Device and not the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for info. I came here to find a solution for archiving without a device, but appearly it is not possible. There is an alternate way with App Loader, some stuff been told here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188383-Can-not-select-App-in-Application-Loader